# Django Migrations Circular Dependencies

Tags: python, django, circular-dependency

so my django project was working completely fine and everything worked.

I wanted to rename an app something else so I did and updated all the associated files in including the app.py config file.

I also cleared the database and removed all migration files from each app.

Ever since then I have never been able to finish makemigrations onto my apps.

I even recreated the app I renamed, by doing django-admin startapp "appname" and then copied the contents of models.py admin.py, etc over to see if I somehow cause an internal issue but I just can't figure out what's going on?.

I did manage to get all the makemigrations to success for all apps including the one I remade when I removed this (below) from another apps admin.py file

```
# accounts/admin.py

class SigBotSettingsInLine(admin.StackedInline):
    model = SigBotSettings

@admin.register(Bot)
class BotAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin,):
    ...
    inlines = [SigBotSettingsInLine]
```

but in the end the python manage.py migrate, still Failed. If someone would help it would be highly appreciated.

Here is the error-code:

```
(dguacENV) PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\djangoProjects\dguac> python manage.py makemigrations accounts
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 88, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 53, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 286, in build_graph
    self.graph.ensure_not_cyclic()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3\envs\dguacENV\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 274, in ensure_not_cyclic
    raise CircularDependencyError(", ".join("%s.%s" % n for n in cycle))
django.db.migrations.exceptions.CircularDependencyError: accounts.0001_initial, accounts.0002_auto_20210809_1814, signals.0001_initial
```

Dependencies in accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
dependencies = [
    ('signals', '__first__'),
    ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
]
```

Dependencies in accounts/migraitons/0002_auto_20210809_1910.py

```
dependencies = [
    ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
]
```

Dependencies in signals/migrations/0001_initial.py

```
dependencies = [
    ('accounts', '0002_auto_20210809_1910'),
]
```

Comment: Are the `accounts` and `signals` apps your own code? What are the `dependencies` in each of the migrations in these apps? Please [edit] your question to show these.

Comment: Note that the problem is circular dependencies in your migrations, not circular imports in your python code as your original title suggested. Hopefully this clarification can help you track down the problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure what you meant "What are the dependencies in each of the migrations in these apps?" so i shared the models.py files for both apps in the question.

Comment: So i realised what you were talking about and read about the problem and flow of migrations here - https://django.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/migrations.html

But looking through all my models, none of them should conflict and cause this?

and to make matters worse, It as working already completely fine, before I just renamed the app originally and added the @admin.register() class.

Comment: Looks like you found what I was asking for. I'll post an answer shortly.

Comment: Feel free to include the models as well. All the fields and functions aren't needed for the purposes of your question. However, you do need to look at imports to see if any are circular. Of course, python will tell you if this is a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Dependencies in accounts/migrations/0001_initial.py
>
> ```
> dependencies = [
>     ('signals', '__first__'),
>     ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length'),
> ]
> ```
>
> Dependencies in accounts/migraitons/0002_auto_20210809_1910.py
>
> ```
> dependencies = [
>     ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
> ]
> ```
>
> Dependencies in signals/migrations/0001_initial.py
>
> ```
> dependencies = [
>     ('accounts', '0002_auto_20210809_1910'),
> ]
> ```

This tells us the following:

1. `accounts.0001.initial` depends on `signals.0001_initial` (specified by `'__first__'`.
2. `accounts.0002_auto_20210809_1910` depends on `accounts.0001.initial`
3. `signals.0001_initial.py` depends on `accounts.0002_auto_20210809_1910`

The circularity should be clear.

You can either edit these dependencies manually or delete all migrations and generate them again with `./manage.py makemigrations` This should solve the problem unless there are underlying issues with the model dependencies themselves.

### **WARNING**

Be very careful when editing or deleting migrations. If your project is deployed to a live server, editing migrations that have already applied will at best do nothing and at worst completely wreck your production database. The proceeding suggestion should only be used if you are working on a project that has not yet been deployed.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

So yes thank you a lot for pointing out about the migration dependency issue, reading that link made me clearly understand how the makemigrations function works.

So after I looked through my dependencies, I found that in my Signals.models file there was a foriegnkey that linked to the Signals app before it was migrated.

I commented out this foreignkey line then migrated and everything worked perfectly.

I even added the foreignkey back afterwards and updated the migration which also worked because at this point the signal database had already been migrated.

I know this is bad practice though and will he changing the way that foreignkey is linked through another method.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: For foreign keys, you can can use a string with the model's qualified name rather than the actual class name. This should solve part of the problem. Of course, the issue might be deeper than this, but it sounds like you have a way forward. Good luck!

Comment: For circular import that does solve the issue. But I was already using a string reference to the model. like so 'signals.OpenSignal'  | The problem was that it was trying to make migrations to a column that didn't exist yet.

Comment: It essentially did this

1. make account model
 1b. Try to make model field that has a foreignKey linking to 'signals.OpenSignal'

2. make signals model
 2b. try to make model field that has a forienkey linked to 'accounts.Bot'

The migration works but when you go to migrate, django now has 2 dependencies conflicting. Accounts importing signals, and signal importing from accounts.

Comment: That makes sense. So it sounds like you are solving the design problem here as you break up your models into separate apps. That is more complex than my initial naive suggestion in my answer. But at least you understand what the problem is and can work on a solution.

Comment: If you need more help as you continue working on this, you should post a new question. Include a link to this one if it is appropriate to give some context.